Oracle APEX - trigger before update of column on table with Interactive Grid
I've created a trigger that copies the value from COL_A to COL_B. It works only with changes on COL_A, and in SQL Developer everything works fine. I can change other columns values but it doesn't trigger it. When I update COL_A, COL_B gets value of COL_A.
create or replace trigger BU_COL_A 
  before update of COL_A on TABLE_ABC            
  for each row 
begin  
   :new.COL_B := :new.COL_A;  
end;

When I try repeat that on Interactive Grid, unfortunately it doesn't work. Any change in any column triggers it. Any idea how to fix that?
[APEX 19.1]
